# How to get back accidentally deleted `wpa_supplicant` file?

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I was trying to get Ad-Hoc working on my Konka i127 Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2 phone, and I accidentally deleted my `wpa_supplicant` file. Now, I cannot turn on my Wi-Fi connection anymore.

How do I get my `wpa_supplicant` file back?

Comment: Finished factory reset, and it added a new file right in it's place. But I still cannot connect to Wi-Fi, any ideas?

Comment: Well that's a different question which should be asked as a NEW question. As for this question, I believe it is answered. So should I post an answer, or you would do it for us? :)

Comment: Done, I have asked a new question, here it is. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116785/need-help-wi-fi-problems

Answer (score 1):

The `wpa_supplicant.conf` resides at the location `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Since it is inside `/data/`, rest assured that it is not lost for eternity. It would take factory reset to bring it back from scratch.

Also, that file contains device specific and your once connected Wi-Fi's specific information. So, there is no point for us to upload it for you.